# iOS: Registration pages ask for 11 pieces of information... Too many?

Tags: ios, registration

So I've got this client that I'm working with and they've got a great registration page put together, but the page is asking for 11 pieces of information. I personally feel that this needs to be split up between a few pages. What are your experiences?

Comment: It's not so much if it's one page vs. multiple but rather just that there's 11 fields.

Comment: Talk to some programmers about how you could get 11 pieces of information without asking them. You may be surprised. I recently removed "address" from a form I worked on, I then got their IP from the request header, queried a 3rd party API to get a rough lat/lon for that IP, then queried google API to get a rough address from lat lon. Depending on what you need the data for, there could be some more user friendly workarounds to get it.

Comment: @Sam what if you work in a company that uses an internal net so connection to internet is in another country?

Comment: @Mark, if it's technically not possible then as you know it's technically not possible. This was a comment not an answer, as it <i>could</i> be an answer based on question clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the user's interaction with the site (in terms of difficulty to proceed) to be a shallow line rather than a vertical cliff face. As the user gets more out of the site they are more likely to reciprocate by giving you more info about themselves. Asking for lots upfront is likely to A cause lots of people not to even bother registering, B cause people to put in lots of fake data just to get through.

But don't take my word for it, run an experiment with 1/2 user's doing it with it all upfront and 1/2 drip feeding. Then you have solid data on which to move forward. In the long run, the expense of this experiment should be justified by more customers.

edit: Just found this blog post which summarizes what I was saying:
https://baymard.com/blog/simplifying-sign-up

Comment: I also would add that data shows that there's no effect on completed sign-ups when splitting forms between pages or keeping it on one page. Nice answer @AndyM.

Answer (score 1):

Yes 11 is too much.

Here's what you can do to improve.

For the first time, just ask for the **least amount of info that'll do for a start.** Like if you're a shopping app, minimum would be name and email (gender too!?). Yes you need the address too but you  can postpone it. **Get them started fast!** Ask for additional info, if you can't skip it, the next time they use the app. (I'd prefer the 5th time they use the app)

Second, maybe you can **pull half of the info you need from facebook or google!** Encourage them to use these open ID logins, it'll be easier for both user and developer.

Comment: re last para - not all users will have details or correct details on public IDs